# div height 100% but not over absolute sticky footer

Tags: css

I try to make a div expand in height, but it's expanding over the absolute positionned sticky footer at the bottom, here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMLKf/1/

(I don't need to support old browsers)

Comment: Please provide a better jsfiddle with the footer and the div or the whole sourcecode.

Comment: @Alex sorry, something went wrong when I saved my jsfiddle, I updated the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `margin-bottom: 200px` rule will only affect subsequent elements in the document flow. It will *not* make your div 200px smaller than the browser window. To demonstrate I've set up a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GnWZg/).

If you want the bottom of your div to be 200px from the bottom of the browser window, you could absolutely position it with `top: 0` and `bottom: 200px`. [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cuZnu/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your main div:

```
#content { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 200px; }
```

and footer:

```
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 200px; }
```

This could probably work with position: relative as well.

EDIT:

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/nQVPm/

I'm pretty sure this works on IE7+